# Using Curl with Kubernetes nginx Ingress #5116

Tags: curl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I configured authentication through nginx to a specific service in k8s.

It works fine with WUI.

I saw some examples

This works fine too:

`curl -v http://10.2.29.4/ -H 'Host: foo.bar.com' -u 'foo:bar'`

But i need to close other part my url same.

For example /api/v1/upload

I deployd 2nd ingress with path:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service
          servicePort: 8000
        path: /api/v1/upload
```

Without nginx i got to type:

`curl -XPOST 'file=@/file' http://10.2.29.4:8000/api/v1/upload -H "Authorization:key"`

How do i need to try use curl for hide real ip or port and get a good result?

I would really appreciate if you could help me figure it out.

ingress1:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mobsf
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mobsf
#    env: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: mobsf-basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: worker1.mydomain.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: mobsf
          servicePort: 8000
```

Ingress 2:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mobsf2
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mobsf2
#    env: dev
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: mobsf-basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Authentication Required"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: worker1.mydomain.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: mobsf2
          servicePort: 8000
        path: /api/v1/
```

DNS check (correct):

```
 nslookup worker1.mydomain.local
Server:         10.2.67.10
Address:        10.2.67.10#53

Name:   worker1.mydomain.local
Address: 10.2.67.203
```

Services:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          159d
minio-service   LoadBalancer   10.233.32.19    <pending>     9001:30809/TCP   104d
mobsf           NodePort       10.233.18.34    <none>        8000:30426/TCP   8d
vault           NodePort       10.233.43.134   <none>        8200:30820/TCP   69
```

Ing:

```
 kubectl get ing
NAME     HOSTS                  ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
mobsf    worker1.dev002.local             80      2d1h
mobsf2   worker1.dev002.local             80      23h
```

Comment: Do you want to use authentication for both paths "/" and "/api/v1/upload"? Please post all the ingress yaml with details about the authentication of both ingresses.

Comment: I did it, plz check

Comment: And yes, I want to use auth for both paths / and /api/v1/upload

Comment: In this case you don't need to have 2 ingress, you could configure a single ingress with both paths. But it works, what is the real problem? Are not able to use `worker1.mydomain.local` for you requests? If you try to resolve `worker1.mydomain.local` using nslooup or dig is it correct and pointing to your ingress ip ? Please share the result of the command `kubectl get svc` and `kubectl get ing`.

Comment: I know, that i can make 2 path in 1 yml file. It was just attempt , I added outputs u ask

Comment: Are you using a bare metal installation of Kubernetes? Because your ingress doesn't have `EXTERNAL-IP`

Comment: Yes its bare metal

Answer (score 1):

In bare metal installations is not possible to use `Ingress` and `LoadBalancer` services by default. You can't get `EXTERNAL-IP`, as displayed in the outputs that you provided.

The first `curl` command you provided show that you are using your service `mobsf` as `NodePort`, it means you are able to reach your application typing IP of your node + port like this `http://<NODE_IP>:8080`, but without authentication since you are not accessing the server through the ingress.

Here is all service types and how that works:

> - `ClusterIP`: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default  `ServiceType`.
> - [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport): Exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (the  `NodePort`). A  `ClusterIP`  Service, to which the  `NodePort`  Service routes, is automatically created. You’ll be able to contact the  `NodePort`  Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting  `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`.
> - [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer): Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider’s load balancer.  `NodePort`  and  `ClusterIP`  Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.

#### How to use LoadBalancer and Ingress in bare metal installations?

The Nginx [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) shows how to setup **MetalLB** to allow your bare metal cluster the usage of LoadBalancer Services.

> [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) provides a network load-balancer implementation for Kubernetes clusters that do not run on a supported cloud provider, effectively allowing the usage of LoadBalancer Services within any cluster.

Basically, the setup is easy:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.8.3/manifests/metallb.yaml
```

And then create a ConfigMap to configure:
*- Edit the ip range according yout network*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250 <= EDIT IP RANGE
```

Check the installation typing `kubectl get pods -n metallb-system`, this is an expected output:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n metallb-system
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
controller-65895b47d4-6wzfr   1/1     Running   0          9d
speaker-v52xj                 1/1     Running   0          9d
```

After **MetalLB** installed and configured you should be able to use your ingress and Loadbalancer services.

Here there's an example of how setup a Service (ClusterIP) and Ingress:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mobsf
spec:
  selector:
    app: mobsf
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: mobsf-ing
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - foo'
spec:
  rules:
  - host: worker1.mydomain.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: mobsf
          servicePort: 8000
      - path: "/api/v1"
        backend:
          serviceName: mobsf
          servicePort: 8080
```

Check your ingress with the command `kubectl get ing` and look for in `EXTERNAL-IP` column.

After that make sure you configure in your local DNS an entry for `worker1.mydomain.local` pointing to the ip above.

Please let me know if that helped

Comment: Wow! thx u for feedback! small refinement, first curl doesnt work without creds. And i get my app with worker1.domain.local with auth too correct! maybe this is changing something?

Comment: @cryptoparty, Could explain in more details? Did you tried the steps I posted and didn't work ?

Comment: No, this is just clarification, maybe you misunderstood me, I have not tried to add a configmap yet

Comment: The same results :-(